# How can I refer to a class from another project in the same Workspace in Eclipse/Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two projects in my Eclipse ADT Android/Java workspace

```
MyProject
MyProjectAutomatedUITests
```

In MyProject, there is a package `.constants` with a class `ButtonNames.java` that is full of constants

I want to be able to use the members of that class from MyProjectAutomatedUITests

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add your `MyProject` to the build path of your `MyProjectAutomatedUITests` by right clicking the project than `Properties>Build Path>Projects>Add` and select your project, by doing this you can use the classes of `MyProject`.

But if you just want only one class than you should create another one for your ptoject.